# Limit of probability of intersection with sequence of events

Tags: probability

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of independent events such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n)=1$.

Then it holds that 
$$\lim_n \mathbb{P}(A_n \cap A)=\mathbb{P}(A) \quad  \forall A \in \mathscr{A}$$

We have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n \cap A)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{P}(A|A_n) \cdot\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(A_n)=\mathbb{P}(A) \cdot 1 = \mathbb{P}(A)$$

is this at all correct?

Comment: What is the justification for $\lim\limits_n \mathbb{P}(A_n\cap A)=\mathbb{P}(A)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim P(A_n \cap A) =\lim P(A) +\lim P(A_n ) -\lim P(A_n \cup A) =P(A) +1-1 $$